# document.onload not working for me?

Tags: javascript

Well I'm simply playing around with a userscript of GreaseMonkey and here's just something simple I attempt to do;

```
function test() {
document.getElementById('elementhere').innerHTML = 'test';
}
document.onload = test();
```

It works if I go to the page I want to use it on and do "run" or "reload & run" - but it won't run automatically, which I'm trying to make it do by using document.onload.

Answer (score 29):

What you need is:

```
window.onload = function () {
// do the work after everything was loaded (DOM, media elements)
}
```

**document.onload** it doesn't exist. It works if you at least target some specific element from document for example:

```
document.querySelector("img").onload = function ()
 {// do your thing after 'img' was loaded}
```

You have other options if you want to execute some code after the DOM is the only element ready without wait for media elements to load like:

- Import an async script tag loading the file with the code:
   You can place this tag wherever you want in DOM and it will not interrupt nothing, will load after the DOM finish to load. you should take a look to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) about that.
- If you take a look again in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) they will recommend you in section **Notes** to use DOMContentLoaded and DOMFrameContentLoaded events which can be handling by addEventListener. So, if you do this:

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handlerFunc);

Will work for you.

I hope this can be helpful for you...

Answer (score 14):

When you write `document.onload = test()`, you are *calling* the `test` function, and *assigning* its return value to the `onload` handler. This is clearly not what you intended.

```
document.onload = test;
```

This will *assign* a reference to the `test` function to the `onload` handler. When the event fires, *that* is when your function will be called.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are assigning the result of the `test` function instead of the function itself due to the parentheses `()` on the last line.
Remove them and it may work.

If not then:

Apparently that is by design. [`Chrome - v57`]
Use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", <function_name>);` instead.

See: [Page lifecycle : DOMContentLoaded](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe do this:

```
<body onload="test()">
```

Or is that not what you're looking for? If you want to do it without the HTML bit above, maybe try and replace document with window:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
   document.getElementById('elementhere').innerHTML = 'test';
}
```

I would give that a go because of this:

[window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

I know that posting a link to a link is lame, but you will see why I did that (hopefully).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

No Need to call the function on the page .. just you need to use below code which is best practices of coading

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working but you can use alternate

```
window.init = test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Greasemonkey then you don't really need a using onload event since the Greasemoneky script is called only when `DOMContentLoaded` is fired.

> The code in a Greasemonkey user script gets invoked when the
>   DOMContentLoaded event fires (during event capture as of GM 0.8.6). It
>   is a DOM event implemented by Mozilla, **similar to window.onload.**
>   However, since it waits only for the DOM to load, instead of the
>   entire page (including images, style sheets, and etc.) it happens
>   sooner.

http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded

I think you would just need to call `test()` without any event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

did you try this?

```
<body onload="test()">
```

or

```
    $(document).ready(function test() {
    document.getElementById('elementhere').innerHTML = 'test';
    }
```