# Change Color for iPhone visitor

Tags: javascript, html, ios

How can i change the color of an element, depending if the visitor is using ios (iPhone)?

This is what i tried:

`<p id="TestID">Change this color for iPhone</p>`

`document.onload = function myFunc(){`

```
if( (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1)) 

     document.getElementById("TestID").style.color = "red !important";);}
```

But it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here how i check for users' device. maybe this works for you too.

```js
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    // android users
} else if (/iphone/i.test(userAgent) || /ipad/i.test(userAgent)) {
    // ios users
}
```

for your case, try:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if (/iphone/i.test(userAgent) || /ipad/i.test(userAgent)) {
        document.querySelector("#TestID").style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

also you used `document.onload` incorrectly. [more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960838/document-onload-not-working-for-me)

Comment: Many thanks
But how can i apply styling with this code?
Can you write it out so i can straight up copy it? New to JS @Layhout